# Sort Perl numeric array

Tags: perl, arrays, sorting, numeric

I have an array which looks like this:

```
array[0]: 6 8
array[1]: 12 9 6
array[2]: 33 32 5
array[3]: 8 6
```

I want to sort this array so that it looks like this:

```
array[0]: 6 8
array[1]: 6 9 12
array[2]: 5 32 33
array[3]: 6 8
```

I know I can sort the array with `@newarray = sort {$a cmp $b} @array;`, but I need to sort the elements in each line as well. How can I do that?

Comment: is that an array of arrays or are they strings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update 2021-03-16**: Dear future visitors, I have the accepted answer, and I'm still getting upvotes, but [@FMc's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3280092/26702) is clearly better than mine. (FMc and dalton have the same answer, but as far as I can tell, FMc got there first.)

In any case, if you have a situation like this use Perl's built-in [map](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map) rather than my original answer of a custom subroutine.

**Original answer**: Assuming that you have an array of strings there, and that all you want is to sort each string as if it were a sub-array of numbers (but leave it a string?):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = ('6 8', '12 9 6', '33 32 5', '8 6');

foreach my $string (@array) {
    $string = split_sort($string);
}

sub split_sort {
    my $string = shift @_;
    my @internal_nums = split ' ', $string;
    @internal_nums = sort {$a <=> $b} @internal_nums;
    return join ' ', @internal_nums;
}

print "@array\n";
```

Answer (score 7):

You could also solve it using map:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

my @numbers = (
    '6 8',
    '12 9 6',
    '33 32 5',
    '8 6',
);

my @sorted;
push (@sorted, map { join " ", sort { $a <=> $b }  (split / /, $_) } @numbers);


print "$_\n" for @sorted;
```

Outputs:

```
6 8
6 9 12
5 32 33
6 8
```

Comment: +1 for a solution that is much shorter, easier to understand and more efficient than a foreach loop with a subroutine call on each iteration.

Comment: +1 for the same reasons, though it could be shortened considerably: `map { join " ", sort split } @numbers` should work.

Comment: @Jon Actually, no, that won't work. You still need a numeric sort - `map { join " ", sort {$a <=> $b} split } @numbers`.

Comment: @Telemachus: Darn. I guess my Perl is a tad rusty.

Answer (score 5):

You have a **list of items that you want to transform**. That's a perfect candidate for [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html). Also note the default behavior of [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html): it operates on `$_`, splitting on whitespace, after removing leading whitespace.

```
my @array = ('6 8', '12 9 6', '33 32 5', '8 6');
@array = map { join ' ', sort {$a <=> $b} split } @array;
```